# How to check RgPlugn PopUp null or not in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, plugins, popup

I use RgPlugn PopUp page in my xamarin app and I want to check if this pop pages open or not because I kick user from app when session time is over. If there is no RgPlugn PopUp page it will go null exception error.
How can I check RgPlugn PopUp page is null or not ? I use this code to kick out user.

```
 private void RedirectAndInformInactivity()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Oturum Sonlandı!", "İşlem yapmadığınız için oturumunuz sonlandırılıyor!", "Tamam");
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new LogoutPage());

        });
    }
```

Comment: why not catch the exception?

Comment: How can I use try and catch here ? I'm new at xamarin forms and programming.

Comment: wrap the line causing the exception in a try/catch block

Comment: try
                {
                    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                } Lİke this ?

Comment: yes, something like that

Comment: Unfortunatelly, It doesn't work.

Comment: if you just need to know if any pages exist, then you can check the `PopupStack` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check whether a pop-up has been opened.

```
//Verifying whether any popup pages are present in the PopupStack
//It returns true if there are any pop-up pages in the PopupStack.
if (Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PopupStack.Any())
{
    List<PopupPage> popupPageList = new List<PopupPage>();
    popupPageList = Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PopupStack.ToList();
    
    // popupPageList contains all of the pages that are present in the PopupStack, which you can validate according to your requirements.
}
else
{
    //Popup stack is empty
}
```

Comment: This works well. Thank you very much Chary Jagdeesh